# Combining two click functions into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got two click functions from different contexts - one to filter some elements with jquery isotope and another one to mimic dropdown functionality with an unordered list.

The dropdown works, but because of the two click functions I have to double click the list item to close the dropdown.

Could anybody help me to combine these two click functions into one?

I've got a nice little **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alani/QVFDv/)** and the script for preview:

```
$(function(){
    var $container = $('#container'),
        filters = {};

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        filter: '',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        animationEngine: 'css',
        containerStyle: {
            position: 'relative',
            overflow: 'hidden'
        },
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 2500,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }

    });

    ////////// first click function: filter links

    $('.filter a').click(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      // don't proceed if already selected
      if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
        return;
      }

      var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
      // change selected class
      $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $this.addClass('selected');

      // store filter value in object
      // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
      var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
      filters[ group ] = $this.attr('data-filter-value');

      // convert object into array
      var isoFilters = [];
      for ( var prop in filters ) {
        isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
      }
      var selector = isoFilters.join('');
      $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

      return false;
    });



    ////////// Second Click function for faux Dropdown (replace span)

    function DropDown(el) {
                this.dd = el;
                this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
                this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
                this.val = '';
                this.index = -1;
                this.initEvents();
            }
            DropDown.prototype = {
                initEvents : function() {
                    var obj = this;

                    obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                        $(this).toggleClass('active');
                        return false;
                    });

                    obj.opts.on('click',function(){
                        var opt = $(this);
                        obj.val = opt.text();
                        obj.index = opt.index();
                        obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
                    });
                },
                getValue : function() {
                    return this.val;
                },
                getIndex : function() {
                    return this.index;
                }
            }

            $(function() {

                var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

                $(document).click(function() {
                    // all dropdowns
                    $('.wrapper-dropdown').removeClass('active');
                });

            });
});
```

Comment: Not sure I get it, are you trying to do this -> http://jsfiddle.net/QVFDv/2/ ... ?

Comment: if you return false, it's going to prevent the other click event from happening. don't return false.

Comment: Try `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;` (You'll need to add the `e` parameter to your click function handler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to remove `return false;` from your `$('.filter a').click()` event handler. ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QVFDv/5/))

It's cutting the execution of all other code. I recommend you use something like [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) instead (I've updated the jsFiddle to include this).

Comment: If I want to use multiple dropdowns, with different IDs, how do I have to change the script? At the moment there's only one ID (#dd) used, I guess I have to store multiple IDs in an array, right?

Comment: I think adding `var dd2 = new DropDown( $('#otherID') );` in your document ready handler should do it.

Comment: Thanks again, both dropdowns are working, but the filter functionality is broken now, it should be a combination filter. When I choose a land and then a type I get the right results. But when I then choose "any" for type all filter options are set back, it then also shows any land, but the land I selected first should stay active. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alani/QVFDv/8/)

Comment: [Here's the fully working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QVFDv/9/). I would like to take it to chat to explain the changes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33162/discussion-between-yotam-omer-and-alani)

Comment: huh, didn't know that I need reputation for this. Anywhere else? but I really don't wanna take away your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle the .active class in the first click function:

```
//...
////////// first click function: filter links
$('.filter a').click(function(){
  $('.wrapper-dropdown').toggleClass('active'); // Added this!
  var $this = $(this);
  // don't proceed if already selected
  if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
    return;
  }
 //...
```